# reverse order of paragraphs in file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file containing text in paragraphs (lines with text separated by one or more empty lines). I would like to reverse the order of paragraphs (i.e. last paragraph will become the first, ...), preferably by using sed.

I am looking for a sed command which would do to a file of paragraphs, what `tac` would do to a file of lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sed` isn't quite as straight-forward as mentioned by [Joseph R.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26909/joseph-r).  However, you could say:

```
sed '/./{H;d;};x;s/\n/={NL}=/g' inputfile | \
sed -e 's/^={NL}=//' -e '1!G;h;$!d' | \
sed G | sed 's/={NL}=/\'$'\n/g'
```

Given a sample input:

```
Para 1 line 1
Para 1 line 2
Para 1 line 3

Para 2 line 1
Para 2 line 2
Para 2 line 3

Para 3 line 1
Para 3 line 2
Para 3 line 3
```

this would produce:

```
Para 3 line 1
Para 3 line 2
Para 3 line 3

Para 2 line 1
Para 2 line 2
Para 2 line 3

Para 1 line 1
Para 1 line 2
Para 1 line 3
```

It's worth mentioning that this solution (as well as the alternate Perl one) require a blank line at the end of the input file in order to work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

This solution uses both `tac` and `perl` to read a paragraph at a time. It does not require reading the whole file into memory.

```
tac file | perl -00 -lpe '$_ = join "\n", reverse split /\n/'
```

Reverse all the lines of the file, then for each reversed paragraph, reverse the lines.

Comment: This looks very elegant and efficient. However, this solution also condenses multiple empty (i.e separating) lines into one

Answer (score 3):

There might be a way to do this with `sed`, but I doubt it will be simple. Here's how I would do it in Perl:

```
perl -n00e 'push @paragraphs,$_; END{print for reverse @paragraphs}' your_file
```

This works because defining the input record separator as the null character (`-00`) tells Perl to operate in paragraph mode. [Perl's definition of a paragraph<sup>1</sup>](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/18/variables.html) matches your definition exactly.

---

<sup>1</sup>Look under the heading `Other values for $/`

Comment: this works indeed. The only small problem is, it does not preserve multiple empty lines separating the paragraphs. Instead, all paragraphs are separated by exactly one empty line.

Answer (score 1):

If your paragraphs are always separated by a single empty line:

```
sed '/^$/s/^/\x02/' infile | tr \\n$'\002' $'\003'\\n | \
sed 's/^\x03//;1s/\x03$//;1!G;h;$!d;$a\' | tr $'\003' \\n
```

It's quite easy to see how it works if you break it into pieces and run
`sed '/^$/s/^/\x02/' infile` then `sed '/^$/s/^/\x02/' infile | tr \\n$'\002' $'\003'\\n` and so on...

---

If your paragraphs are separated by one or more empty lines, e.g.

```
Para 1 line 1
Para 1 line 2

Para 2 line 1


Para 3 line 1
Para 3 line 2

Para 4 line 1
Para 4 line 2



Para 5 line 1
```

and you want to reverse the order of paragraphs but preserve the order of "empty blocks" you could read the file twice:
1st: turn paragraphs into single lines (removing empty blocks in-between) and reverse them and
2nd: turn the empty blocks into single lines, "indexing" the number of empty lines in each block (and removing non-empty lines)
then `paste` the results and process the output to restore newlines:

```
paste -d $'\004' <(sed '/^$/s/^/\x02/' infile | tr \\n$'\002' $'\003'\\n | \
sed -e '/^\x03$/d;s/^\x03//;s/\x03$//;1!G;h;$!d;$a\') \
<(sed -E '/^$/!d;//{:a;N;/^(\n){1,}$/ba;s/\n/\x02/g;s/(.*)\x02.*/\1/}' infile) \
| sed '$!s/\x04/\n/;$s/\x04$//' | tr $'\003\002' \\n\\n
```

which outputs:

```
Para 5 line 1

Para 4 line 1
Para 4 line 2


Para 3 line 1
Para 3 line 2

Para 2 line 1



Para 1 line 1
Para 1 line 2
```

If you don't mind an extra trailing line in the output you could drop the last `sed`:

```
paste -d $'\n' <(sed '/^$/s/^/\x02/' infile | tr \\n$'\002' $'\003'\\n | \
sed -e '/^\x03$/d;s/^\x03//;s/\x03$//;1!G;h;$!d;$a\') \
<(sed -E '/^$/!d;//{:a;N;/^(\n){1,}$/ba;s/\n/\x02/g;s/(.*)\x02.*/\1/}' infile) | \
tr $'\003\002' \\n\\n
```

These assume that first and last line aren't empty (and no `\x02`, `\x03` or `\x04` in the input).

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do it with a single instance of `sed`; no pipes necessary.  Since `sed` only makes one pass through the document and since the portion of the file required as the *beginning* of the output is at the *end* of the file, it will require holding the entire file in memory inside `sed` (in the hold space)—so it may not scale well.  But it answers the question exactly:

```
:getpara
   ${
      s/$/\
/
      G
      s/\n\n$//
      q
   }
   N
   /\n$/!bgetpara
G
h
$!d
s/\n\n$//
q
```

If there is no trailing newline, this still works fine.  If there is a single trailing newline, it is suppressed in the output (i.e. there will not be a leading newline in the output).  If there are (for example) 5 trailing newlines in the input, there will be 4 leading newlines in the output.

The gaps between paragraphs are preserved.

Whitespace on an otherwise empty line is NOT treated as a paragraph break, but that's a feature, not a bug.  :)

You can also do this as the much less readable one-liner:

```
sed ':k;${;s/\(\(\n\).*\)$/\1\2/;G;s/\n\n$//;q;};N;/\n$/!bk;G;h;$!d;s/\n\n$//;q' inputfile
```

Although this only works with GNU `sed`.  (Note the tricky use of backreferences to perform `s/$/\n/`.  Without this it wouldn't be a literal one-liner as it would contain a backslash-newline.)

Comment: so you slurp the file, right? it looks like you put the whole thing in hold space. w/ `G;h`. you might mention something about input restrictions or similar.

Comment: I didn't test the one-liner because I'm working from my Mac and don't have GNU `sed` handy, but the script version definitely preserves the gaps between paragraphs.  I just tested it on your input.  Did you test the script version?

Comment: @mikeserv: Definitely true.  (Will update tonight.)

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install facets

ruby -r facets/string \
     -e 'puts $stdin.read.strip.shatter(/\n\n+/).reverse.join("")' < file
```

This should preserve your paragraph spacing (while being more readable than `sed` :) ) Although, props to devnull for an awesome answer.